# Anyway to recover dropped table partition in oracle 12c when recycle bin is disabled?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

we are doing bi monthly partioning for oracle database, when we did this month wrongly we have dropped old tables , is it recoverable??? note:Orcale Recycle bin is **disabled**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation

> When the recycle bin is disabled, dropped tables and their dependent objects are not placed in the recycle bin; they are just dropped, and you must use other means to recover them (such as recovering from backup).

So, you'll need to work with your DBA's to restore from back.